# Было and infinitive

Tags: грамматика

I am trying to read a book in russian:
"Быть императрицей. Повседневная жизнь на троне." by Елена Первушина but sometimes  I have problems understanding. I have doubts. Could you please tell me how would you translate in english Было  in this sentence:"Было от чего впасть в отчаяние и раздражение." This is the context: «Оставленная мужем, она наглядно, чуть не ежедневно видела его измену и постоянно встречала предмет его любви – лукавую Марию Антоновну… Было от чего впасть в отчаяние и раздражение. И как часто бывает в таких случаях, в это самое время подвернулся молодой кавалергард, который влюбленно смотрел на Елизавету». Thank you very much in advance to all of you who will be so kind to try and help me.

Answer (score 3):

"Было от чего" means "There was a reason".